# Разбор html файла на haskell

Tags: html, xml, парсер, xpath, haskell

Занимаюсь сейчас разбором web страничек на haskell. Для этого использую модули Text.XML и Text.XML.Cursor.
Нужно разобрать html страницу и получить всё содержимое нужных тегов.
Например есть той html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2 class="title">
<b>ss</b> aa
<a href="link">LINK</a>
</h2>

<h2 class="title">
<b>qq</b> 22
</h2>

<h2>BAD</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Код на haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Prelude hiding (readFile)
import Text.XML
import Text.XML.Cursor

main :: IO ()
main = do
    doc <- readFile def "page.html"
    let cursor = fromDocument doc
    print $
        cursor $// element "h2"
               >=> attributeIs "class" "title"
               &// content
```

В результате я получаю список строк вида:

```
["\n","ss"," aa\n","LINK","\n","\n","qq"," 22\n"]
```

Мне, в свою очередь, нужен такой список:

```
["ss aa LINK", "qq 22"]
```

Как понимаю, требуемого результата можно добиться используя корректные операторы модуля Text.XML.Cursor?

Comment: Посмотрите на пакет `tagsoup` (`fast-tagsoup`) - возможно он больше подойдёт для разбора html

Comment: Александр, я смотрел этот пакет. С ним тоже не вышло и там более запутанный поиск необходимых тегов. В Cursor формируется xpath запрос, а в tagsoup каждый тег самому приходится отсеивать.